# Most efficient way to select elements in 2d array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, select, matrix, direction

Let's say I have 2d array (or matrix) like,

```
matrix = [
 [1, 2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [7, 8, 9]
]
```

And, I've to select all elements in eight directions of a certain element `matrix[i][j]`, so I know,

- up and down elements will have same `j`
- left and right elements will have same `i`
- back-inclined diagonal (`\`) elements will have same diff `i-j`
- front-inclined diagonal (`/`) elements will have same sum `i+j`

How to select those elements, easily and efficiently? Any direct method?

---

For example, if my element is `4`, then my selection should yield, `[1, 7, 5, 6, 2, 8]`. If it is, `5`, then selection should be *all except* `5`.

---

**Edit:** I've coded any solution yet, as I thought it'll be very poor, but here is my idea. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU3LDoIwEDy7XzGJR1Yjvk3gS0hDAEso4WFqDRDLt2OBo5edx87u6E86TFOdGK16hIgIkc84Mk6CHT8zLozrwm@MO@MhSBBp@Z7TgpSDA5Vu@kRbVNIgUlwKpBKqecoebY56gKxkLRtDa9NeJlkRd8oU8RL6Wt12rC0c/O@ytuLMgjZzaxDAaagcGcIQJay7mplamLe4ylv93ap2JWgciV5wH6bpBw)

```
matrix = [
 [1, 2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [7, 8, 9]
]

res = []
i = 0
j = 1

# let [i,j] be index of my element
matrix.each_with_index{|row,r| row.each_with_index{|col,c| 
    res << col if c == j || r == i || r+c == i+j || r-c == i-j 
}}

p res
```

Comment: I will suggest you try first as SO is to help you and not to provide puzzle problems solution

Comment: @ray - I'd already found the conditions to check, and I can use `select` very poorly, but that wouldn't be efficient and easy to implement

Comment: @iGian - Which element do you feel is wrong / not included?

Comment: @vrintle also assuming 2D matrix is not symmetric, you are providing input as `[1,0]` instead of `4` It will be a more sensible question.

Comment: Is the array of arbitrary size? Are the elements supposed to be yielded in a specific order? And last not least: since you ask for "most efficient" I assume that you already have an inefficient solution / attempt – show it, please.

Comment: @ray - The 2d matrix isn't square / symmetric, it can be any kind of matrix. Yes, you can either have index pair / element.

Comment: @Stefan - The input matrix can be of any type, just non-empty. And, output is free as I've to just check a condition on every selection. This is Day 11, part 2 of AoC

Comment: Are elements unique in the matrix? Or how can you find the coordinates of the element in case you have any duplicates?

Comment: @iGian - You'll have index as well as the element in the start.

Comment: I think your solution is fine so long as the array is not excessively large. You do need a small fix, however: `...if (r != i || c != j) && (c == j || r == i || r+c == i+j || r-c == i-j)`

Answer (score 2):

`m` is the matrix you have taken from a user that is a symmetric or non-symmetric 2-dimensional array.

```
# inputs
m = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ]
p, q = 1, 0 # co-ordinate of number 4

# code for output
i, j, result = m.size, m[0].size, []

i.times { |r| result.push(m[r][q]) if r != p }
j.times { |c| result.push(m[p][c]) if c != q }
i.times do |r|
    j.times do |c|
        result.push(m[r][c]) if [p,q] != [r,c] && (p-r).abs == (q-c).abs
    end
end
> result
 => [1, 7, 5, 6, 2, 8]
```

**Note:** if the order of output is not needed to be preserved, we can manage with only 2 loops

Comment: Regarding efficiency: although it's just 2 loops, this always traverses each element.

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

```
def extract(matrix, row, col)
  last_row = matrix.size-1
  last_col = matrix.first.size-1
  diag_sum = row + col
  diag_first_row = diag_sum - [diag_sum, last_col].min
  diag_last_row  = [last_row, diag_sum].min
  ante_diag_diff = row - col
  ante_diag_first_row = [ante_diag_diff, 0].max
  ante_diag_last_row = ante_diag_diff +
    [last_col, last_row - ante_diag_diff].min
  arr = [] 
  (0..last_col).each { |j| arr << matrix[row][j] unless j == col }
  (0..last_row).each { |i| arr << matrix[i][col] unless i == row }
  (diag_first_row..diag_last_row).each do |i|
    arr << matrix[i][diag_sum - i] unless i == row
  end
  (ante_diag_first_row..ante_diag_last_row).each do |i|
    arr << matrix[i][i - ante_diag_diff] unless i == row
  end
  arr
end
```

**Example**

```
matrix = Array.new(5) { Array.new(5) { rand(10..99) } }
  #=> [[52, 29, 61, 35, 27],
  #    [68, 99, 67, 18, 67],
  #    [79, 10, 73, 15, 36],
  #    [49, 94, 28, 24, 53],
  #    [37, 26, 65, 65, 43]]
```

```
(0..4).each do |i|
  (0..4).each do |j|
    puts "#{i}, #{j}: #{extract(matrix,i,j)}"
  end
 end
```

```
i  j
----------------------------------------------------------------------
0, 0: [29, 61, 35, 27, 68, 79, 49, 37, 99, 73, 24, 43]
0, 1: [52, 61, 35, 27, 99, 10, 94, 26, 68, 67, 15, 53]
0, 2: [52, 29, 35, 27, 67, 73, 28, 65, 99, 79, 18, 36]
0, 3: [52, 29, 61, 27, 18, 15, 24, 65, 67, 10, 49, 67]
0, 4: [52, 29, 61, 35, 67, 36, 53, 43, 18, 73, 94, 37]
```

```
1, 0: [99, 67, 18, 67, 52, 79, 49, 37, 29, 10, 28, 65]
1, 1: [68, 67, 18, 67, 29, 10, 94, 26, 61, 79, 52, 73, 24, 43]
1, 2: [68, 99, 18, 67, 61, 73, 28, 65, 35, 10, 49, 29, 15, 53]
1, 3: [68, 99, 67, 67, 35, 15, 24, 65, 27, 73, 94, 37, 61, 36]
1, 4: [68, 99, 67, 18, 27, 36, 53, 43, 15, 28, 26, 35]
```

```
2, 0: [10, 73, 15, 36, 52, 68, 49, 37, 61, 99, 94, 65]
2, 1: [79, 73, 15, 36, 29, 99, 94, 26, 35, 67, 49, 68, 28, 65]
2, 2: [79, 10, 15, 36, 61, 67, 28, 65, 27, 18, 94, 37, 52, 99, 24, 43]
2, 3: [79, 10, 73, 36, 35, 18, 24, 65, 67, 28, 26, 29, 67, 53]
2, 4: [79, 10, 73, 15, 27, 67, 53, 43, 24, 65, 61, 18]
```

```
3, 0: [94, 28, 24, 53, 52, 68, 79, 37, 35, 67, 10, 26]
3, 1: [49, 28, 24, 53, 29, 99, 10, 26, 27, 18, 73, 37, 79, 65]
3, 2: [49, 94, 24, 53, 61, 67, 73, 65, 67, 15, 26, 68, 10, 65]
3, 3: [49, 94, 28, 53, 35, 18, 15, 65, 36, 65, 52, 99, 73, 43]
3, 4: [49, 94, 28, 24, 27, 67, 36, 43, 65, 29, 67, 15]
```

```
4, 0: [26, 65, 65, 43, 52, 68, 79, 49, 27, 18, 73, 94]
4, 1: [37, 65, 65, 43, 29, 99, 10, 94, 67, 15, 28, 49]
4, 2: [37, 26, 65, 43, 61, 67, 73, 28, 36, 24, 79, 94]
4, 3: [37, 26, 65, 43, 35, 18, 15, 24, 53, 68, 10, 28]
4, 4: [37, 26, 65, 65, 27, 67, 36, 53, 52, 99, 73, 24]
```

**Explanation**

First observe that if the target element is in row `i` and column `j`, the elements `[p,q]` on the diagonal that passes through that point have the property that `p+q == i+j`. Similarly, the elements `[p,q]` on the ante-diagonal that passes through that point have the property that `p-q == i-j`

Suppose

```
row = 1
col = 2
```

then

```
last_row = matrix.size-1
  #=> 4 
last_col = matrix.first.size-1
  #=> 4 

diag_sum = row + col
  #=> 3 
diag_first_row = diag_sum - [diag_sum, last_col].min
  #=> 0 
diag_last_row  = [last_row, diag_sum].min
  #=> 3 

ante_diag_diff = row - col
  #=> -1 
ante_diag_first_row = [ante_diag_diff, 0].max
  #=> 0 
ante_diag_last_row = ante_diag_diff +
  [last_col, last_row - ante_diag_diff].min
  #=> 3
```

The remaining calculations are straightforward.

---

Here's a variant of the above that uses less code and may be slightly less efficient.

```
def extract(matrix, row, col)
  row_range = 0..matrix.size-1
  col_range = 0..matrix.first.size-1
  diag_sum = row + col
  ante_diag_diff = row - col
  arr = [] 
  col_range.each { |j| arr << matrix[row][j] unless j == col }
  row_range.each do |i|
     next if i == row
     arr << matrix[i][col]
     j = diag_sum - i
     arr << matrix[i][j] if col_range.cover?(j)
     j = i - ante_diag_diff
     arr << matrix[i][j] if col_range.cover?(j)         
  end
  arr
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample code, you can modify/simplify it further

```
class Matrix
  attr_reader :arr, :ele

  def initialize(arr, ele)
    @arr = arr
    @ele = ele
  end

  def find_elements
    position = arr.flatten.index(ele)
    len = arr.length
    x = position % len
    y = position / len
    horizontal_elements(y) + vertical_elements(x, y, len) + remaining_elements(x, y, len)
  end

  def horizontal_elements y
    arr[y] - [ele]
  end

  def vertical_elements x, y, len
    rows = (0..(len-1)).to_a - [y]
    rows.map{|row| arr[row][x] }
  end

  def remaining_elements(x, y, len)
    rows = []
    rows << y + 1 if y + 1 < len
    rows << y - 1 if y - 1 >= 0
    c_rows = []
    c_rows << x + 1 if x + 1 < len
    c_rows << x - 1 if x - 1 >= 0
    rows.map{|row| c_rows.map{|c_row| arr[row][c_row] } }.flatten
  end
end

matrix = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
]
ele = 4
(1..9).each do |i|
  puts '*' * 20
  puts "For #{i}"
  puts Matrix.new(matrix, i).find_elements.inspect
  puts '*' * 20
end
```

O/P will be something like following

```
Desktop $ ruby something.rb
********************
For 1
[2, 3, 4, 7, 5]
********************
********************
For 2
[1, 3, 5, 8, 6, 4]
********************
********************
For 3
[1, 2, 6, 9, 5]
********************
********************
For 4
[5, 6, 1, 7, 8, 2]
********************
********************
For 5
[4, 6, 2, 8, 9, 7, 3, 1]
********************
********************
For 6
[4, 5, 3, 9, 8, 2]
********************
********************
For 7
[8, 9, 1, 4, 5]
********************
********************
For 8
[7, 9, 2, 5, 6, 4]
********************
********************
For 9
[7, 8, 3, 6, 5]
********************
```

Answer (score 0):

### A recursive way

I'd like to propose a different approach, not tested if it is more or less efficient but can provide some control on order and more.

Lets start with this matrix, where elements tell their indexing:

```
mat = [
  ['00', '01', '02'],
  ['10', '11', '12'],
  ['20', '21', '22'],
  ['30', '31', '32']
]
```

And define an helper method just to get the shape of the matrix and to check which is well formed:

```
def shape(mat)
  raise 'Out of shape' if mat.map(&:size).uniq.size > 1
  return mat.size, mat[0].size
end
```

### Implementation

Now, let's define a method that takes as input the starting point, the limits of the matrix (shape) and the direction.

```
def walk(i_0, j_0, i_max, j_max, direction, res=[])
  d_i, d_j = direction
  next_step = [i_0 + d_i, j_0 + d_j]
  if [-1, i_max].include?(next_step[0]) || [-1, j_max].include?(next_step[1])
    return res
  end
  res << next_step
  i_0, j_0 = next_step
  walk(i_0, j_0, i_max, j_max, direction, res)
end
```

The method returns the list of indexes starting from the origin and walking along the direction.

### Usage examples

#### Example 1

```
i_0, j_0 = [2, 0]
i_max, j_max = shape(mat)
direction = [-1, 1]
walk(i_0, j_0, *shape(mat), direction)
#=> [[1, 1], [0, 2]]
```

#### Example 2

You can use it to extract the indexes given a list of directions.

It's possible to arrange the list of directions to give a scan order (clockwise, cclockwise) or just skip some directions, as you will.

```
directions = [[1, 0], [-1, 0], [0, 1], [0, -1], [1, 1], [1, -1], [-1, 1], [-1, -1]]

i_0, j_0 = [2, 0]
directions = [[1, 0], [-1, 0], [0, 1], [0, -1], [1, 1], [1, -1], [-1, 1], [-1, -1]]
directions.flat_map { |direction| walk(i_0, j_0, *shape(mat), direction) }
#=> [[3, 0], [1, 0], [0, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [3, 1], [1, 1], [0, 2]]
```

#### Example 3

(Which is an extension of example 2)
You can directly get the elements from the matrix:

```
res = directions.flat_map do |direction|
  walk(i_0, j_0, *shape(mat), direction).map do |coords|
    i, j = coords
    mat[i][j]
  end
end

res
#=> ["30", "10", "00", "21", "22", "31", "11", "02"]
```

---

It can be possible to use a longer step (eg. `direction = [2, 2]`) upgrading the `walk` method.